# XPath is valid in Chrome but not in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath

My challenge is to locate an element by its content which contains single-quotes. I do this successfully with vanilla JS here:

```js
singleQuotes = document.evaluate("//div[contains(text(), \"'quotes'\")]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 

singleQuotes = singleQuotes.snapshotItem(0);

console.log(singleQuotes)
```

```html
<div>'quotes'</div>
```

However, when I use Python & Selenium to implement the same vanilla JS, the Xpath is invalid:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

window = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
window.get("www.someurl.com")
window.execute_script(f'''xpath = document.evaluate("//div[contains(text(), \\"'quotes'\\")]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);''')
```

I get a SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string...is not a valid XPath expression.

(I would try & show this in a sandbox but I don't know how to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's just the " getting eaten by python. Use a double \\.

Forget selenium and compare:

```
print(f'''xpath = document.evaluate("//div[contains(text(), \"'quotes'\")]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);''')
```

and

```
print(f'''xpath = document.evaluate("//div[contains(text(), \\"'quotes'\\")]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);''')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string...is not a valid XPath expression
```

...implies that the xpath based [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have constructed was not a valid locator.

---

### Solution

You can use either of the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using the complete text *`'quotes'`*

  ```
  singleQuotes = document.evaluate("//div[text()=\"'quotes'\"]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  ```
- Using partial text *`quotes`*

  ```
  singleQuotes = document.evaluate("//div[contains(., 'quotes')]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try backticks:

```
document.evaluate(`//div[contains(text(), "'quotes'")]`, ...)
```